# Magento 2: setup upgrade error "We can't find the role for the user you wanted"

Tags: magento2

I got strange error while running command "php bin/magento setup:upgrade".

Error:
We can't find the role for the user you wanted...

Unable to complete my all command process.

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution:

Please go to file:
vendor/magento/module-authorization/Model/Acl/AclRetriever.php at line# 85 and edit below code into edit one:

Original Code:

```
        if (!$role) {
            throw new AuthorizationException(
                __('We can\'t find the role for the user you wanted.')
            );
        }
        $allowedResources = $this->getAllowedResourcesByRole($role->getId());
```

Edit Code:

```
        if (!$role) {
            $allowedResources = array();
        }
```

Now, please run setup:upgrade and rest commands.

Important:

Once success, please revert back the file.

Thanks,

Comment: Please dont do this. All admin users and permissions might get deleted.

Comment: Indeed, It doesn’t seems to be a permanent solution, it might be the module that is broken somewhere.

Answer (score 16):

in my case it was caused by Shopial_Facebook (which I do not need). I ran

```
php bin/magento module:disable Shopial_Facebook
```

cleared cache and the error was gone. I hope it helps.

Comment: Please note that Shopial_Facebook has been removed from the Magento base as of Magento 2.2.6 so upgrading to 2.2.6 also does the trick.

Comment: Very strange.. thank you for confirming @Isolde that it's a good long-term fix too!